# Map between de Rham cohomologies

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

For two closed manifolds $M$ and $N$ with dimension $m$ and $n$ respectively.

Note: If there is a differential map $f: M\to N$, then for any cohomology class $\beta\in H^*(N)$,  $f^*\beta \in H^*(M)$.

**Q**: Under what kind of condition, the following formula
$$\int_{M}f^*\beta=\int_{f(M)}\beta$$
always holds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, a differential $k$-form can only be integrated over a $k$-manifold. So, in order for your equation to even make sense, $M$ and $N$ must have the same dimension (as if $\beta$ is an $n$-form so too will be $f^*\beta$).

For manifolds of the same dimension, this equation will hold iff $f$ is a degree-1 map (in [this sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_continuous_mapping#Differential_topology)), more or less by definition.